# Can ANN be tuned to improve classification performance. Can ROC be of any use?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, roc

I am learning Neural Network Toolbox in MATLAB. I have tested it on data from the Machine Learning Repository and drawn a graph from calculating ROC given the data. I calculated ROCs for all parts: train, validation, and test. I understand what ROC curves represent, what a particular cutt-off point corresponds to and why we call it a trade-off between TPR and FPR.

[image]

This ROC presents good classifiction but my goal is to have an influence on decision if a classifier provides more TP (with higher TPR) even though I accept more FPR? I can read from the graph that if I expect 90% of TP, I would have to accept slight over 40% of FPR as well. How can this knowledge be of any help to tune current classification performance?

Is there any way, a property in the structure that NN returns (e.g. "patternnet") that would let me tune a classifier according to what ROC shows and then make classifier to give more TRP and FPR? I am not sure if this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase both *TRP* and *FPR*, you actually want to increase your *recall* at expenses of you *precision*

You could modify your cost function and use [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) instead. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/64319-neural-network-how-to-use-a-custom-performance-function), you have more info about how to use a custom performance function in Matlab NN